# Outputting emission with transparency -what am i doing wrong?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, transparency, emission

im trying to render a laserbeam animation. (In EEVEE)
The beams need to be on a transparent background, as they will be projected over an image/animation for a project.

here is the problem: it looks correct in blender when rendering, the background is transparent, the beams glow. i added a glare node in composite and everything looks fine.

[image: Text]

Now when i export the picture as a png or tiff or anything, it wont save the glow/emission , while it shows in the render window. In photoshop it turns up like this: (no glow! - black layer added to show)

[image: Text]

Why doesnt it export the glow/emission ? what am i doing wrong? it drives me quite nuts at the moment ;|

Comment: Hello :). PNGs cannot handle both emissive and alpha pixels (due to it's bad alpha handling). Use EXR instead for compositing.

Comment: hi jachym, trying this EXR still results in the same images as above , but actually trying a few other different image formats, i found out the bmp actually stores the right alpha but still requires me to cut it out manually in photoshop to get it transparent ;/